# How to iterate each form of same class and handle submits uniquely with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I have multiple forms on the same page with the class `form_delete`.

How do I iterate over those forms in jQuery adding a `submit` event that will uniquely apply to each form?

I've tried this using `$('.form_delete').each(...);` but when I add `$(this).submit(...)` events it's not working (event does not register).

Forms:

```
<form class="form_delete">
</form>

<form class="form_delete">
</form>

<form class="form_delete">keep adding n forms to infinity ;)
```

jQuery:

```
$('.form_delete').each(function() {
    $(this).submit( function(event) { 
        // Nothing gets registered here
    });
}
```

Comment: "...that will uniquely apply to each form?" What do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.form_delete').each(function() {
    $(this).on("submit", function(e) { // submit button pressed
        // prevent form from doing what it normally does when submit button is pressed
        e.preventDefault();

        // do anything else that you want to do when the submit button is pressed
        alert( "Hi");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) is also an option.

```
    $('body').on('submit', '.form_delete', function submitCB(e) {
       e.preventDefault();  
    });
```

When the event bubbles up to the `body` then jQuery will check the `target` element against the string selector (parm 2), and only call the callback (parm3) if it matches.

This way you only have on event listener on the page, as opposed to many.

Comment: Thank you...You save my day

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you use .each();  anyway if all forms with same class just use

```
$('.form_delete').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).index());
    return false;
});
```

in that case you will need something like data-selectForm to define which form you submited

```
<form class="form_delete" data-selectForm="firstform">
</form>

<form class="form_delete" data-selectForm="secondform">
</form>
```

and then use

```
$('.form_delete').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).data('selectForm'));
        return false;
    });
```